# Custom validation & messages

Tags: modules, events

I'm trying to add some custom validation rules to user sign up like this:

```
Event::on(
  User::class, Element::EVENT_DEFINE_RULES, static function(DefineRulesEvent $event) {
    $event->rules[] = [['fullName', 'email'], 'required'];
    $event->rules[] = [['password'], 'string', 'min' => 10, 'tooShort' => Craft::t('yii','Password is too short')];
    $event->rules[] = ['password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'confirmPassword', 'message' => Craft::t('yii','Passwords do not match')];
  }
);
```

But I still get 'New Password should contain at least 6 characters.' instead of 10 and no error shows for the password mis-match. The fields on my registration form are:

```
{% macro errorList(errors) %}
  {% if errors %}
    {{ ul(errors, {class: 'errors'}) }}
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

<input name="password" type="password">
{{ user ? _self.errorList(user.getErrors('password')) }}

<input name="confirmPassword" type="password">
{{ user ? _self.errorList(user.getErrors('confirmPassword')) }}
```

Can anyone help me learn why the error won't show?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `User` class already defines a password rule on the `newPassword` attribute.

```php
        $rules[] = [
            ['newPassword'],
            UserPasswordValidator::class,
            'forceDifferent' => $this->passwordResetRequired,
            'currentPassword' => $currentPassword,
        ];
```

Source: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/aad45b7d4c7005a0ac4809f32e135c6eadec7062/src/elements/User.php#L859-L864

And the `UserPasswordValidator` class has a hard-coded minimum password length of `6`.

```php
    public const MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 6;

    public function __construct(array $config = [])
    {
        // Default min
        if (!isset($config['min'])) {
            $config['min'] = self::MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH;
        }

        // Default max
        if (!isset($config['max'])) {
            $config['max'] = self::MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH;
        }

        parent::__construct($config);
    }
```

Source: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/aad45b7d4c7005a0ac4809f32e135c6eadec7062/src/validators/UserPasswordValidator.php#L49-L62

Since your rule is added to the `password` attribute, it has no effect on the `newPassword` attribute.

Here’s how you might replace the default rule with your own:

```php
Event::on(
    User::class,
    User::EVENT_DEFINE_RULES,
    function(DefineRulesEvent $event) {
        // Remove the `newPassword` rule
        foreach ($event->rules as $key => $rule) {
            if (isset($rule[0]) && $rule[0] === ['newPassword']) {
                unset($event->rules[$key]);
            }
        }
        
        // Add your own `newPassword` rules
        $event->rules[] = [['newPassword'], 'string', 'min' => 10, 'tooShort' => Craft::t('yii','Password is too short')];
    }
);
```

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. So is `EVENT_DEFINE_RULES` the right event? I was using `EVENT_BEFORE_VALIDATE` before but ran into some issues there.

Comment: Yes, you're attaching the rules correctly, just using the wrong attribute name.

Comment: Sorry, `password` is incorrect? I don’t have a `newPassword` input, just `confirmPassword`.

Comment: Right, but `newPassword` is the name of the attribute on the `User` element:
https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/aad45b7d4c7005a0ac4809f32e135c6eadec7062/src/controllers/UsersController.php#L1313

Comment: So the input attribute should be `newPassword` and the rule also on `newPassword`? If I do that, I get my error message if it's >6 but <10. But if it's less than 6 I get the Craft error (minimum 6)

Comment: That's because you've added an additional rule, rather than removing the old one. I've updated my answer to show how you might replace the rule.

Comment: Does this answer your question @supazu?

Comment: It definitely helped but I still haven't been able to get it to work. Probably something I'm doing but the errors still aren't working properly. I've shelved it for now, but will mark the answer as technically you are correct I think.